# Postgres automatic insert time stamp with time zone (india)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, timestamp, timezone

Is there any way to insert timestamp with zone automatically when query is inserted ? (just like id auto increment as i don't want to pass the the parameters in sql as time its same every where if we use zone).pg version 9.1. and how to use to desired time format ?

Comment: With which part do you have the problem?  What sort of query do you want to insert?  Are your servers have proper time zone settings?  And finally, what do you mean by desired time format?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I want to give a comment about your question. I can't to do that because I have low reputation here. So, I decided to answer whether it fits with your question or not.

Let's I start. Would you like determine "query is inserted" first?

I have an assumption about your "query is inserted". "Query is inserted" is every query is inserted or affected on database (it could be insert, update, delete, etc.) that will be noted in **log**. Log here means *log table* where the **trigger** handles every query. OK. I give you clear explanation by an example below.

First, make a definition of *log table* like this,

```
CREATE TABLE query_log (
    log_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    log_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    action VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

*Action* column above determines whether query performed by someone (for example when someone do insert, so the action column will be "insert" and so on). Then, we have to make a trigger to handle what we write on *log table*. It depends on table what affected by query. For example, we do query on *table query*. So,

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_insert_query_log
AFTER INSERT ON name_of_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_query_log();
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_query_log() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO query_log VALUES (currval(log_id)), DEFAULT, 'insert');
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

You can continue with another function for update, delete, and etc or you can combine all of them in one function.

Comment: I think you slightly overthought the problem - in my understanding, they just want to have a timestamp with every row inserted.

Comment: Hi 0x54MUR41 Thanks for your critical thinking  and explanation  and time to write and explain :). dezso you are right, I did not mention any thing about log hence dezso is right. I will update the question. Thanks for pointing out for need of more clear explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I am so sorry @Abhijit Gujar I have overthought the problem like dezso said. Now, you can update your question..

Comment: @0x54MUR41 You don't have to be sorry. If every first-time poster spent this much energy on their post, this site would be even awesomer :) You see, you got some nice upvotes for a reason.